# Why is $M\subseteq Mod(Th(M)) $?

Tags: first-order-logic

In first-order logic, an immediate corollary of the definitions of the *theory* of a set of models M (denoted $Th(M)$) and the *Model* of a set of sentences S (denoted $Mod(S)$) is:

> $M\subseteq Mod(Th(M)) $

But how is this proven? (for example, what happens if $Th(M)=\emptyset$ and $M\neq \emptyset$)

Comment: If $\mathrm{Th}(M) = \emptyset$ then $\mathrm{Mod}(\mathrm{Th}(M))$ is the class of all structures. So of course $M \subseteq \mathrm{Mod}(\mathrm{Th}(M))$ in that case. The general case is just a matter of unfolding the definitions.

Comment: $\operatorname{Th}(M)$ can't be empty, it must at least contain all the logically valid sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Th(M)$ is the set of all sentences true in $M$. Take $A \in M$ and $\phi$ such that $A \vDash \phi$, then $\phi \in Th(M)$. By definition, $A \in Mod(Th(M))$.

Comment: about $\phi \in Th(M)$ - the definition says that $\phi$ is valid in *some* $A\in M$ or in *all* $A\in M$?

Comment: The definition says that $\phi$ is valid for for models in M.